# De-select worksheets after printing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2007

I have setup a excel worksheet that uses multiple sheets for calculations that don't need to be printed.  My entire workbook has 8 sheets and I normally only print the first 4.  The workbook may be printed multiple times as I am editing it.

My problem is after selecting the sheets I want to print, and printing them, they stay selected.  I often forget to un-select them and start editing.  That in turn affects the given cell on all of the selected worksheets.  I usually realize this too late and have to rebuild part of my worksheet.

Is there a way to either:
a) force the group of worksheets to be un-selected after printing
or
b) Set a print area over multiple sheets so I can print without needing to select multiple sheets.

I am using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just record a macro.

I would save the macro to the file itself, and create a shortcut key for it so that all you have to do is press 'ctrl+shift+p', for example, and it will print the desired sheets and return the workbook to just having one sheet selected.

1. Press record
2. select the sheets to print
3. Print
4. ungroup the sheets
5. stop recording.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to automatically force it to do so, but you could attempt to get in the habit of using the hot keys to navigate off of the multiple spreadsheets by using CTRL + PageUp/PageDown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro assigned to a hot key, for either of the options

a) http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=125

b) http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003157_Setting_Print_Ranges_for_Multiple_Worksheets.html

Comment: Looking at those links I see ways to set or clear a print area on multiple sheets, but that is not what I need.  I either need to clear the selected sheets, or print out multiple sheets - i.e. sheets 1-4 without first selecting them.